# Generic method how to return all of type T

Tags: c#, generics

say I have the following code:

```
public class Pond
{
  public List<Frog> Frogs { get; set; }
  public List<MudSkipper> MudSkippers { get; set; }
  public List<Eel> Eels { get; set; }
}

public class Frog: IAquaticLife
{

}



public class MudSkipper: IAquaticLife
{

}



public class Eel: IAquaticLife
{

}
```

Now I want to write a generic method that will for a certain pond return the list of these types:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByPond<T>(int pondId) where T : IAquaticLife
{
   return Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId).Eels;
}
```

Ok, so what I have there will return all the eels in that pond. What I was wanting to do was to return all the T's.

so if I called `GetByPond<MudSkipper>(1)` that would return all the mudskippers.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByPond<T>(int pondId) where T : IAquaticLife
{
   return from t in Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId).AquaticLife() 
          where (typeof(t) == typeof(T)) select t;
}
```

or simply (using the approach that @DStanley pointed out before changing his answer)

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByPond<T>(int pondId) where T : IAquaticLife
{
   return Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId).AquaticLife().OfType<T>();
}
```

That requires *Uow.GetByID(int id)* to return all types of creatures in the particular pond that implement *IAquaticLife*.  The alternative, though, is that you hard-code knowledge of the various implementers of *IAquaticLife* into your generic method.  That is not a good idea.

**UPDATE**

Currently a *Pond* has separate collections for *Eels*, *Mudskippers*, etc.  That becomes fragile if you want to add more things that implement *IAquaticLife* as your code evolves because you have to change both *Pond* and the generic method above.

I suggest that instead of separate methods for each type of aquatic life, you instead have a single method that returns everything in the pond that implements *IAquaticLife*, e.g.

```
public class Pond
{
    public IEnumerable<IAquaticLife> AquaticLife() { ... }
}
```

I have updated my code above with this assumption.

Anyone that has a Pond instance and wants to get, say, just the Eels can do this:

```
var eels = pond.AquaticLife().OfType<Eels>();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Pond need to expose a combined list of all its `IAquaticLife` in order to later be able to filter out by type?

Comment: Yes.  But the alternative is to put type specific code into your generic method, which partially defeats the purpose of a generic method.  If you extend your class hierarchy, your generic code breaks if not also updated.  Brittle.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree. I didn't mean to alter the generic method, actually. I was just pointing out that since Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId) returns a Pond, Pond itself will need to be IEnumerable<IAquaticLife> merging all lists, or something similar, to let you filter it.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't compile. A single Pond is returned by Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId) so it doesn't like the where

Comment: I doesn't make any sense that `Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId)` returns all the types of creatures in the particular pond. I think Uow should have a new method that does that.

Comment: @AnonyMouse: I updated my answer with more detail about how I would solve this and why.

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution I'm going to get.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
return Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId).OfType<T>();
```

**EDIT**

Since you've got the collections in separate properties, you could use either a `switch` block to return the right property based on the type, or use reflection to get the property based on the type name.

A better design based on your requirement would be to have a private `List<IAquaticLife>` that would store all of the critters instead of separate properties, but I'll assume that you can't do that right now.

An example of the switch would be:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByPond<T>(int pondId) where T : IAquaticLife
{
    switch(typeof(T))
    {
        case typeof(Eel):
            return Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId).Eels;
        //etc.
        default:
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No property of type {0} found",typeof(T).Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do what he expects. `GetById<Pond>()` should retrieve a Pond, not a collection of `IAquaticLife`

Comment: Yeah as ivowiblo says it's not a collection returned so you can't even get access to OfType

Comment: @AnonyMouse: The design should be such that an `IEnumerable<IAquaticLife>` is returned from GetByID.

Comment: The **EDIT** is a bad design pattern in that you are putting concrete type information into a generic method.  That breaks as soon as someone creates a new class that also implements IAquaticLife.

Answer (score -1):

```
public Pond GetByPond(int pondId)
{
    return Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId);
}
```

If you want your Frogs, do:

```
var frogs = xxx.GetByPond(1).Frogs;
```

If you want your MudSkippers, do:

```
var mudSkippers = xxx.GetByPond(1).MudSkippers;
```

And so on.

If you can call `GetByPond<Frog>(1)`, you can call `GetByPond(1).Frogs`.

If in any case you don't know the `T`, you'll need to create a collection of all of them and filter them by the type. This is also useful if you have intermediate subtype:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByPond<T>(int pondId) where T : IAquaticLife
{
    var pond = Uow.GetByID<Pond>(pondId);
    var life = pond.Frogs.Union(pond.Eels).Union(pond.MudSkippers);
    return life.OfType<T>();
}
```

But you are concatenating the collections just to filter them.

Comment: That is **not** what the OP wants.  `Ok, so what I have there will return all the eels in that pond. What I was wanting to do was to return all the T's.` If those were your downvotes on the other answers, might be wise to reverse them.

Comment: Also, what if someone comes along and implements `Salamander : IAquaticLife`?  Your implementation is then broken.

Comment: The thing is, this is not what generic is for. And alos the answers didn't solve the posted problem!

Comment: I mean, they asume `GetByID<Pond>()` retrieves all the aquatic life and there's no reason for that.

Comment: Your solution is fragile.  @DStanley and I pointed out why and provided a better solution.  Generics are *certainly* not for hard-coding all of the involved types in a generic method, which you have done (which is what makes it fragile).

Comment: Yep, the second option I proposed was using a union of all the aquatic lifes. It could be in the `Pond` or in the method, but it's the same solution @Pablo Romeo proposed in his comment. At least, it was a solution when the other didn't. Glad finally the question have a good answer after all.